# Scala, getting the type parameters of a KList as an HList

Tags: scala, shapeless

Suppose I have an abitrary KList, which for the sake of argument has type constructor Option[_], ie;

```
type Example = Option[Int] :: Option[String] :: HNil
```

Is there a way I can retrieve an Hlist made of the type parameters?

```
type Params = Int :: String :: HNil
```

So, for example I might be able to define some sort of arbitrary getOrElse method

```
getOrElse(ex:Example, default:Params):Params
```

Now I'm looking for something possibly of a form like this (or similar as the type structure I propose might not be feasible).

```
case class MyOptionList[L <: HList](maybes:L) {
  type Concrete = {somehow the hlist params types as an Hlist}
  def getOrElse(default:Concrete):Concrete = ???

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not Miles, but it's possible to accomplish what you're trying to do pretty elegantly with Shapeless's `Comapped`:

```
import shapeless._, ops.hlist.Comapped

case class MyOptionList[L <: HList, C <: HList](maybes: L)(
  implicit val comapped: Comapped.Aux[L, Option, C]
) {
  def getOrElse(default: C): C = default // Not a useful implementation
}
```

And then:

```
scala> val x: Int :: HNil = MyOptionList(Option(1) :: HNil).getOrElse(2 :: HNil)
x: shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.HNil] = 2 :: HNil
```

Note that in some cases it can be more convenient to put the constraint on the method:

```
case class MyOptionList[L <: HList](maybes: L) {
  def getOrElse[C <: HList: ({ type l[x] = Comapped.Aux[L, Option, x] })#l](
    default: C
  ): C = default
}
```

Here the usage is the same, but you don't have the extra type parameter on the case class. If you want to use this approach but constrain the creation of `MyOptionList` to disallow non-`Option` members, you could use `L <: HList: *->*[Option]#λ` in its type parameter list.

Answer (score 4):

@MilesSabin will probably show up with a more elegant answer, but you can construct this recursively by hand, the way many of the Shapeless internal things are written:

```
sealed trait GetOrElse[L <: HList] {
  type Concrete <: HList
  def getOrElse(ex: L, default: Concrete): Concrete
}
object GetOrElse {
  implicit def nil = new GetOrElse[HNil]{
    type Concrete = HNil
    def getOrElse(ex: HNil, default: HNil) = HNil
  }
  implicit def cons[H, T <: HList](implicit tl: GetOrElse[T]) =
    new GetOrElse[Option[H] :: T]{
      type Concrete = H :: tl.Concrete
      def getOrElse(ex: Option[H] :: T, default: Concrete) =
        ex.head.getOrElse(default.head) ::
          tl.getOrElse(ex.tail, default.tail)
    }
  def apply[L <: HList](implicit goe: GetOrElse[L])
    : GetOrElse[L]{type Concrete = goe.Concrete} = goe
}

case class MyOptionList[L <: HList, C](maybes:L)(
  implicit goe: GetOrElse[L]{type Concrete = C}) {
  def getOrElse(default:C):C = goe.getOrElse(maybes, default)
}
```

(It's probably possible to use a type member rather than a type parameter, but I get confused about when the type information for those is eaten, so I tend to prefer to use type parameters everywhere)

Comment: Works like a charm, thats greatly appreciated.  Ill leave it open for a bit to see if we get something from Miles...

Comment: This is a good direct implementation. If Travis hadn't beaten me to it I would also have pointed you at `Comapped`.